# Python - scipy fmin, giving the arguments to fmin

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm a bit of a newbie in Python.
I'm writing a little piece of code in order to find the minimum of a function:

```
import os,sys,matplotlib,pylab
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin

par = [2., 0.5, 0.008]
x1 = 0.4
f2_2 = lambda x, param: param[0] * x**2 + param[1] * x + param[2]
xmin = fmin(f2_2,x1,args = (par))

print xmin
```

it should be very simple, however I am getting this error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "prova.fmin.py", line 9, in <module>

 xmin = fmin(f2_2,x1,args = (par))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 257, in fmin

 fsim[0] = func(x0)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 176, in function_wrapper

 return function(x, *args)

TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)"
```

Could someone help me in understanding this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this out. Looks like you need to say `(par,)` and not just `(par)`. Note that `(par,)` is a tuple, with the variable `par` as a single element, whereas `(par)` just evaluates to `par`: no tuple. The "`args`" keyword of `fmin` expects to find a tuple, not `par`, which in this case is a list.

Edit:
Well, actually, it would seem that `args` doesn't mind receiving a list either. But then, inside of `fmin`, when the function `f2_2` is called, `args` is [unpacked](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), meaning its contents are now passed as arguments to `f2_2`. This means that `f2_2` ends up getting four arguments, viz. `x`, `2`, `0.5` and `0.008` in this case, as opposed to getting just the two arguments `x` and `[2, 0.5, 0.008]`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much, this probably solve some problems that I have in giving arguments to, for example, curve_fit...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the lambda function to accept more arguments, like this:

```
f2_2 = lambda x, *param: param[0] * x**2 + param[1] * x + param[2]
```

Comment: Thank you too, I didn't know this was possible!